# issue with jQuery Cycle plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-cycle

This was the original division:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/DAoya.png]

after applying jquery cycle plugin the image gets out of its bottom border like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4XXgi.png]

Any ideas why ?

Here is the css of the division:

```
#hero {
float: right;
border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
width: 725px;
height: 370px;
background: #666;
}

#wave {
width: 970px;
height: 40px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: url(../img/wave.png) no-repeat bottom left;
}
```

Comment: Where is your HTML code?  All browsers or just one?

Comment: No idea why this was marked down, quite a well presented question for someone new to the site. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cycle plugin uses the z-index, that is likely the source for your problem.  From the cycle plugin code:

```
// set position and zIndex on all the slides
    $slides.css({position: 'absolute', top:0, left:0}).hide().each(function(i) {
        var z;
        if (opts.backwards)
            z = first ? i <= first ? els.length + (i-first) : first-i : els.length-i;
        else
            z = first ? i >= first ? els.length - (i-first) : first-i : els.length-i;
        $(this).css('z-index', z)
    });
```

I'd play with the z-index of the "wave" and see if that doesn't help.

```
#wave {
width: 970px;
height: 40px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: url(../img/wave.png) no-repeat bottom left;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, i would like to show you my appreciation by upvoting you, but stackoverflow wont let me. Thanks a ton again.

Comment: @user867365 you can "accept" the answer to show your appreciation.

Answer (score 3):

Position changed from relative to absolute (by the cycle plugin), which caused a z-index change like @Orbling said.  If you want the border to be on top of the images in the rotator, you absolutely or relatively position them and give them a z-index higher than the container.

To fix: Explicitly position the lower wavy "border" element (`position:relative; or position:absolute;)`* and give it a z-index higher than that of the rotator element.

*giving the element a higher z-index than the rotator will *not work* if the element isn't explicitly positioned. see http://www.webdevout.net/test?0_